# xtightvnc through ssh gateway -- connection refused

Tags: ssh, vnc, ssh-tunneling

Following setup:
homepc -> gateway -> workpc

```
workpc:~$ tightvncserver :12

homepc:~$ ssh -N gatewayuser@gateway -L 1212:workpc:5912
```

Now I try to connect via

```
homepc:~$ xtightvncviewer localhost:1212
xtightvncviewer: VNC server closed connection
```

I also get the output for the tunnel

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Any ideas? I searched the web, but didn't get it working with those as I didn't find the very same setup..

Comment: You're connecting to `localhost:1234` but the local port is `1212`.     Is `AllowTcpForwarding yes` configured in `sshd_config` on gateway?  Does the firewall on workpc allow 5912 in?

Comment: @Creek sorry, port was a typo (corrected). This setting is not set in sshd_config. How can I check the firewall thing?

Interestingly the same procedure is working with ftp.

Comment: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, if the computer runs Linux then you can use `iptables -vnL`, if it runs Windows then `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`.  If it's at your work, behind their firewall, then you may not have any control over it